# Divide navbar in columns for Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

**Problem:**

I would like to make two parts of a navbar in Bootstrap 4 Beta to be exactly the same size and the rest in the center.

- Column 1 contains the brand.
- Column 2 contains links and the content
  should be center.
- Column 3 contains a search field.

Column 1 and 3 should be exactly the same size.

It does not seem to be possible to use columns in navbar as the content does not adjust accordingly?

So I came up with a different solution but column 1 and 3 are not the same size. How do I make sure that column 1 and 3 are always the same? Is there a way without involving custom css?

**HTML code:**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
</nav>
```

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

https://jsfiddle.net/6gc4guw7/

Comment: I belive you have to include bootstrap min.js cdn to make it work properly

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after adding cdn
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js
 add col-xs-4 or col-sm-4 or col-md-4 or col-lg-4 as per required in the class as below.

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="#" class="col-xs-4 navbar-brand">Logo</a>
  <ul class=" col-xs-4 navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="col-xs-4 form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
</nav>
```